# Validar un correo específico en visual basic

Tags: vb.net, vb

Necesito validar un correo con el siguiente dominio.

correo.prueba@empowering.zapto.org

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular pero aún estando tan completa, no me ayuda para validar el mencionado.

```
expr = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@]+)*)|(.+))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Alguien me podría ayudar porfa?

Comment: No seria mas facil parsear?

Comment: Hola Aaron, validar direcciones de correo electrónico con expresiones regulares es por lo general una mala idea. Pero si es eso lo que buscas, se han realizado ya varias preguntas sobre el tema en el sitio y tienen respuesta (puede no ser exactamente vb, pero la expresión regular en sí te debería funcionar igual). Te recomiendo que les eches un ojo y pruebes a ver si te funcionan. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: Cómo lo harías entonces? es la única manera que conozco, me podrías ayudar porfa?

Comment: Aparte de eso, y como en la otra pregunta que hiciste sobre expresiones regulares y emails, [la expresión regular que compartes valida sin problemas la dirección que quieres](https://regex101.com/r/VEIAED/1). Entonces, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Un ejemplo de por qué es una mala idea: [ésta es la expresión regular para validar correctamente emails](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) generada con Perl usando la gramática especificada en el estándar de mensajes de texto de internet ([RFC 822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt)). Como puedes ver no es una expresión regular sencilla, y cualquier otra que uses que sea más simple va a significar que va a dejar sin validar alguna dirección que sí es válida.